# Error: Expecting a declaration TicTacToe Game

Tags: c++, matrix, char

Hello yesterday I started Programming a little Tic Tac Toe game but today I found a mistake. The game ends in Draw if a return of '/'(just 'X' or 'O' if somebody wins) is shown and the counter shows 9 but it also ends if I make a mistake during game and input e.g. 34 (possible inputs are 1-9) and I reach 9 (Counter).

I want to change the '/' to 'B'
and use
but I get 'Expected a declaration' at **{**.

```
char Checker();
{
    if (matrix[0][0] && matrix[0][1] && matrix[0][2] && matrix[1][0] && matrix[1][1] && matrix[1][2] && matrix[2][0] && matrix[2][1] && matrix[2][2] == 'X' || 'O')
        return 'B';
}
```

Can you help me fix this problem? If you want to see the full Code: https://pastebin.com/E5TzAG4t.
Sorry for my English its just a language I learned at School (Germany).

Edit: This is the Checking Code 1. to see if somebody wins 2. i there was made a Mistake during number insert

```
char Win()
{
    //Spieler X
    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[0][1] == 'X' && matrix[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[1][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][0] == 'X' && matrix[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[0][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[0][2] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    //Spieler O
    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[0][1] == 'O' && matrix[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[1][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][0] == 'O' && matrix[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[0][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[0][2] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

        return '/';
}
char Checker()
{
    if (matrix[0][0] && matrix[0][1] && matrix[0][2] && matrix[1][0] && matrix[1][1] && matrix[1][2] && matrix[2][0] && matrix[2][1] && matrix[2][2] == 'X' || 'O' || '1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || '7' || '8' || '9')
        return 'B';
}
```

Comment: `'O'` is always true so the if statement is always true. Meinst du vielleicht `matrix[2][2] == 'X' || matrix[2][2] == 'O'`? Also, why is there a `;` after `char Checker()`?

Comment: `char Checker();` better get rid of the `;` here..

Comment: If you want to check whether `p` is either `'X'` or `'O'`, you do `if ((p == 'X') or (p == 'O'))`, not `if (p == 'X' or 'O')`.

Comment: With respect to `'Expected a declaration'`: `char Checker();` just defines a function named Checker that returns a char. It defines no body for the function because there's a semicolon after it. So those two things are related.

Comment: Your opening paragraph doesn't explain clearly what you have done and what you are trying to achieve. What do you expect your 'if' condition to do? It doesn't check that all elements are either 'O' or 'X'. Lastly, all paths should return a value from Checker().

Comment: Like Paul said, I don't think that if statement is doing what you think it's doing. If we ignore the fact that it's always true because of the `|| 'O'`, it just checks whether there's a non-zero value in most of the tic-tac-toe positions.

Comment: The Return 'X' or 'O' is at another char it returns an '/' and to check if the game is over I made this

Comment: So do you want to check if all elements of `matrix` have either an 'X' or an 'O' in them?

Comment: yes thats what I want. But now I have another problem. my game ends in Draw if I insert a wrong number

Comment: You'll have to take each problem one at a time.

Comment: StackOverflow is mostly 1 problem per question. It's not fix all the bugs in my code. You can ask additional new separate questions about the other bugs.

Comment: ok sorry it just was for Information

Comment: @SummerAnimations https://godbolt.org/g/5STUAJ. (disclaimer: I didn't test it)

Comment: Thank you now it Works except if I do a mistake it changes Player

Comment: If I make* a mistake. Let me know if you don't want me to correct your English. My German is worse than your English :), that's for sure. As for your problem, you will need to check that the user input was valid and only change state / perform actions if the input was valid.

Comment: Yeah make a function that takes an input and validates it. I did the same

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you want

```
 if (matrix[0][0] && matrix[0][1] && matrix[0][2] && matrix[1][0] && matrix[1][1] && matrix[1][2] && matrix[2][0] && matrix[2][1] && matrix[2][2] == 'X' || 'O')
```

to mean 'if m00 and m01 etc is X or O' sadly thats not what it means. YOu have to say it the long way

```
if((m00 == 'o' || m00 == 'x') && (m01 == 'o' || m01 == 'x') ...
```